# I get an error when triggering an action with a script

Tags: magento-1.9, jquery

EDIT

I'm still getting an error with repeated information on the page when I use the Direct Sctipt as outlined below.

does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

ORIGINAL QUESTION

I have radio buttons on my site with the options of YES and NO. when set to yes it brings up a further option of the user to input.

My current code checks the Yes Button by default when the page loads, but doesn't trigger the button to take effect and bring up the further options

I'm looking for a way to trigger the Yes button automatically on page load.

I'm New to Magento and don't know anything about Jquery in order to make it work

if someone could take a look at the code and advise me on how to proceed I'd be very grateful

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined'){
        document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
    }
</script>
<?php 
$helper=Mage::helper('marketplace'); 
$profile_hint_status = $helper->getProfileHintStatus();
?>
<li class="field" id="wantptr">
    <label for="wantpartner" class="required"><?php echo $helper->__('Do You Want To Become A Seller / Vendor?') ?> </label>
    <?php
    if($profile_hint_status && Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_profile/become_seller',Mage::app()->getStore())){?>
        <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('marketplace/images/quest.png'); ?>" class='questimg' title="<?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_profile/become_seller',Mage::app()->getStore()) ?>"/>
    <?php
    } ?>
    <div class="input-box">
        <input type="radio" id="wantpartner" class="wantpartner" name="wantpartner" value='1' title="<?php echo $helper->__('Agree as Seller') ?>" checked /> <?php echo $helper->__("Yes"); ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="radio" id="wantpartner" class="wantpartner" name="wantpartner" value='0' title="<?php echo $helper->__('Disagree as Seller') ?>" /> <?php echo $helper->__("No"); ?>
    </div>
</li>
<script>
<?php
if($profile_hint_status && Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_profile/shopurl_seller',Mage::app()->getStore())){
    $shopurl_hint = '<img src="'.$this->getSkinUrl('marketplace/images/quest.png').'" class="questimg" title="'.Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_profile/shopurl_seller',Mage::app()->getStore()).'"/>';

}else{
    $shopurl_hint = '';
} ?>
var $wk_jq= jQuery.noConflict();
$wk_jq(function(){
    $wk_jq('#email_address').parents('li').after($wk_jq('#wantptr'));
    $wk_jq('#wantptr').show();

    $wk_jq('.wantpartner').change(function(){
        if($wk_jq(this).val()==1){
            $wk_jq('.button').attr('disabled','disabled');
            $username=$wk_jq('<li/>').addClass('profileurl')
                                    .append($wk_jq('<label/>')
                                        .addClass('required')
                                        .text('<?php echo $helper->__('Shop URL'); ?>')
                                        .append($wk_jq('<em/>').text('*')))
                                    .append('<?php echo $shopurl_hint ?>')
                                    .append($wk_jq('<div/>')
                                        .addClass('input-box')
                                        .append($wk_jq('<input/>').addClass('input-text')
                                            .attr('title','<?php echo $helper->__(' Shop URL For Your Marketplace Shop ')?>')
                                            .addClass('required-entry')
                                            .attr('type','text')
                                            .attr('name','profileurl'))
                                        .append($wk_jq('<span/>')
                                            .text('<?php echo $helper->__(" (This will be used to display your public profile) ")?>')
                                            .addClass('required-entry')
                                            .attr('type','text'))
                                    )
                                    .append($wk_jq('<div/>')
                                        .attr('id','wk_load_conf')
                                        .append($wk_jq('<img/>')
                                            .attr('src','<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('marketplace/images/ajax-loader-tr.gif'); ?>')
                                            .attr('height','20px')
                                            .attr('width','20px')));
            //$wk_jq('#wantptr').next('li').after($username);
            $wk_jq('#wantptr').after($username);
        }else{
            $wk_jq('.button').removeAttr('disabled');
            $wk_jq('.profileurl').remove();
        }
    });
    $wk_jq('ul').delegate('.profileurl input','keyup',function(){
        $wk_jq(this).val($wk_jq(this).val().replace(/[^a-z^A-Z^0-9\.\-]/g,''));
    });
    $wk_jq('#form-validate').delegate('.profileurl input','change', function(){
        $wk_jq('.unavailable,.available').remove();
        var profileurl=$wk_jq('.profileurl input').val();
        $wk_jq('.button').attr('disabled','disabled');
        if(profileurl!=''){
            $wk_jq('#wk_load_conf').show();
            $wk_jq.ajax({
                url:'<?php echo $this->getUrl("marketplace/seller/usernameverify")?>',
                type:'POST',
                data:{profileurl:profileurl},
                dataType:'JSON',
                success:function(data){
                    $wk_jq('#wk_load_conf').hide();
                    if(data==0){
                        $wk_jq('.button').removeAttr('disabled');
                        $wk_jq('.profileurl').append($wk_jq('<span/>').addClass('available success-msg').text('<?php echo $helper->__("available")?>'));
                    }else{
                        $wk_jq('.profileurl').append($wk_jq('<span/>').addClass('unavailable error-msg').text('<?php echo $helper->__("unavailable")?>'));
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

EDIT

We worked it out as this

```
<div class="input-box">
    <input type="radio" id="wantpartneryes" class="wantpartner" name="wantpartner" value='1' title="<?php echo $helper->__('Agree as Seller') ?>" /> <?php echo $helper->__("Yes"); ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="radio" id="wantpartner" class="wantpartner" name="wantpartner" value='0' title="<?php echo $helper->__('Disagree as Seller') ?>" /> <?php echo $helper->__("No"); ?>
</div>

<script> 
function getdata(){ 
$wk_jq("#wantpartneryes").prop("checked", true); 
$wk_jq("#wantpartneryes").trigger("change"); } setTimeout(getdata,700);
</script>
```

though it's not perfect, it works but when it triggers the additional option it repeats it's self on the page

Edit

The Direct Code posted in the answer below with the revisions work perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you radio button have same id's change. Then add the below jquery. Add this code after the fields:

```
<div class="input-box">
    <input type="radio" id="wantpartneryes" class="wantpartner" name="wantpartner" value='1' title="<?php echo $helper->__('Agree as Seller') ?>" checked /> <?php echo $helper->__("Yes"); ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="radio" id="wantpartner" class="wantpartner" name="wantpartner" value='0' title="<?php echo $helper->__('Disagree as Seller') ?>" /> <?php echo $helper->__("No"); ?>
</div>

<script>

 function getdata(){ 
    $wk_jq("#wantpartneryes").prop("checked", true);
    $wk_jq("#wantpartneryes").trigger("change");
 }

 setTimeout(getdata,700);
</script>
```

you can also run direct code.

```
 <script>
           $wk_jq("#wantpartneryes").prop("checked", true);
           $wk_jq('.button').attr('disabled','disabled');
            $username=$wk_jq('<li/>').addClass('profileurl')
                                    .append($wk_jq('<label/>')
                                        .addClass('required')
                                        .text('<?php echo $helper->__('Shop URL'); ?>')
                                        .append($wk_jq('<em/>').text('*')))
                                    .append('<?php echo $shopurl_hint ?>')
                                    .append($wk_jq('<div/>')
                                        .addClass('input-box')
                                        .append($wk_jq('<input/>').addClass('input-text')
                                            .attr('title','<?php echo $helper->__(' Shop URL For Your Marketplace Shop ')?>')
                                            .addClass('required-entry')
                                            .attr('type','text')
                                            .attr('name','profileurl'))
                                        .append($wk_jq('<span/>')
                                            .text('<?php echo $helper->__(" (This will be used to display your public profile) ")?>')
                                            .addClass('required-entry')
                                            .attr('type','text'))
                                    )
                                    .append($wk_jq('<div/>')
                                        .attr('id','wk_load_conf')
                                        .append($wk_jq('<img/>')
                                            .attr('src','<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('marketplace/images/ajax-loader-tr.gif'); ?>')
                                            .attr('height','20px')
                                            .attr('width','20px')));
            //$wk_jq('#wantptr').next('li').after($username);
            $wk_jq('#wantptr').after($username);
   </script>
```

after i checked the **live code**  there was jquery error add these line will solve that

```
var $wk_jq=jQuery.noConflict();

$wk_jq("#wantpartneryes").prop("checked", true); 

$wk_jq("#wantpartneryes").trigger("change");
```

Comment: thanks for for that, I've made the changes you mentioned but the script isn't triggering the yes button when the page loads. When the page loads it still operates as though non of the buttons have been checked

Comment: make trigger `change` to `click` in both places then check

Comment: I can see only one instance of the trigger `change` is there somewhere else I should be changing it also?

Comment: `$wk_jq( ".wantpartner" ).trigger( "click" );` and your function `$wk_jq('.wantpartner').click(function(){`

Comment: like this? `<div class="input-box">
    <input type="radio" id="wantpartneryes" class="wantpartner" name="wantpartner" value='1' title="<?php echo $helper->__('Agree as Seller') ?>" checked /> <?php echo $helper->__("Yes"); ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="radio" id="wantpartner" class="wantpartner" name="wantpartner" value='0' title="<?php echo $helper->__('Disagree as Seller') ?>" /> <?php echo $helper->__("No"); ?>
</div>

<script>
    $wk_jq("#wantpartneryes").prop("checked", true);
    $wk_jq( ".wantpartner" ).trigger( "click" ); 
    $wk_jq('.wantpartner').click(function(){
</script>`

Comment: `$wk_jq("#wantpartneryes").prop("checked", true); $wk_jq( "#wantpartneryes" ).trigger( "click" );` add these two line only rest will take care

Comment: updated the code try that and feedback

Comment: I added those lines and the the Yes button is checked but not clicked, I have to click NO then back to YES for it to take effect

Comment: do you have live link of that?

Comment: add another solution check that

Comment: that just removes it completely

Comment: use `var $wk_jq=jQuery.noConflict();` on first line

Comment: Ok that brings it back but it still has the same issue with Yes being checked but not triggered, I tried changing `change` to `click` and it's still the same

Comment: add this at the end of page mean after other script or use this code `<script>

 function getdata(){ 
    $wk_jq("#wantpartneryes").prop("checked", true);
    $wk_jq("#wantpartneryes").trigger("change");
 }

 setTimeout(getdata,700);
</script>`

Comment: leave that read last two comment and apply that

Comment: Ok that works, but with an error ... it's bringing up the additional option twice

Comment: use one code remove f you added twice and kindly accept answer to help the community too.

Comment: Hi thanks I haven't repeated any of the code but it still brings it up twice

Comment: i check it is not repeating.. check may your browser cache issue

Comment: I've just checked it on three browsers and the Shop URL option is repeating it's self on all of them

Comment: i think you already used `checked` in field use one either code or input

Comment: yeah I used `checked` I've removed that and it makes no difference I've also tried removing `$wk_jq("#wantpartneryes").prop("checked", true);` and `$wk_jq("#wantpartneryes").trigger("change");` and it ether repeats or dosn't trigger. I can't see any reason why it would repeat

Comment: Wow thank the Direct code and update you posted worked Perfectly! thank you! and sorry for taking up so much of your time